# What does "Tu peux toujours courir !" mean?

Tags: sens, expressions-idiomatiques

I encountered this while reading *Astérix gladiateur*, and I can't make heads or tails of this sentence. The bard Assurancetourix has been captured and brought to Caesar as a gift. In Caesar's court he is standing in chains and thinking to himself:

> Tu peux toujours courir pour que je chante pour toi ! Et tu ne sais pas ce que tu perds!

This seems to mean:

> You can always run so that I sing for you! And you won't know what you're missing!

Which of course makes no sense. Am I misunderstanding the role of *courir* here?

Comment: Here are some similar expressions : "*Tu peux rêver !*", "*Tu peux te gratter !*", "*Crève !*".

Comment: *Tu peux te brosser !* too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Tu peux (toujours) courir* is an idiomatic expression meaning that something will not happen, even with your best efforts. Something like: even if you try very hard (presumably by running very fast towards somewhere), it won't happen. Here, Assurancetourix will not sing, no matter what.

[CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/courir) gives:

> Fam. *Tu peux toujours courir!* Tu auras beau faire, tu n'obtiendras pas ce que tu veux.
>
> Proverbe. *Il vaut mieux tenir que courir* (cf. un tiens vaut mieux que deux tu l'auras).

Comment: We can say *"Cours toujours !"* too.